# SQL Server 2014 : remove duplicate records based on one of several fields in the row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to remove rows with duplicate `accountno`'s from my table.

```
SELECT ACCOUNTNO, DateTime, RESULTCODE, REF 
FROM dbo.Most_Recent_Result
```

I have tried `DISTINCT` but the REF is different on some of the rows.

How do I remove duplicate `accountno`'s? I just want to remove the second matching `accountno` record.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Obviously, your question makes no sense, if the values of all three columns are not exactly the same -- that is the definition of a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row per account number, use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT ACCOUNTNO, DateTime, RESULTCODE, REF
FROM (SELECT mrr.*,
             row_number() over (partition by accountno order by datetime desc) as seqnum
      FROM dbo.Most_Recent_Result
     ) mrr
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I am creating a SQL View and getting the "SQL cannot be presented in the grid" message